# My UseEffect content delays my DOM rendering in Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

sorry but I still don't understand something. I have a user page and at the end of the page I thought about creating a component that would render the option of traveling for three other users. Like "friend suggestions". As it is a resource that is at the end of my page, I thought about saving loading and rendering only when the page loaded. However, when debugging this user page, I realized that the component I placed inside useEffect was delaying the loading of my page. The code is below. Usually, I always thought that every resource that was inside useEffect was a resource that would never delay loading the DOM. But as I am using Next.Js, I am confused about this situation. It would be nice to understand, but even more so to resolve this code of mine, if someone has a suggestion, thanks.

[image]

---

*User page
mywebiste.com/user/thomas*

```
 async function getServerSideProps(ctx){
        const user = await api.get( '/user-id');
        return user
 }
    
 export default function PageUser( { user }){
    
    const [ footerUsers , setFooterUsers ] = useState()
    
    useEffect((){
       handleFooter()
    },[user])
    
    async function handleFooter(){
       const others_users = await api.get('/other-users')
       setFooterUsers(other_users)
    }
    
     return ( <>
                 <h1> Hello {user.nome}</h1>
                 <UsersFooter users={footerUsers}/>
             </>
     )
 }


function UsersFooter({ users }){
 return 
    users.map( user => <h1> I'm {user.name}</h1> )
}
```

My intention is that I can get rid of this process of having to search the users' api and render the DOM calculation component and load it with javascript when the page is already loaded, something that with useEffect and Next.Js I couldn't.

EDIT

I'm still trying to get it right. It is really something that is beyond my understanding. Because my data is only generated inside useEffect and even then it insists on delaying the DOM.

Comment: Shouldn't `handleFooterUsers` and `getServerSideProps` be declared `async`? You also appear to have variable naming inconsistencies. Are these just typos in trying to pare down your code to a minimal example or do you have some real typos in your code?

Comment: I forgot to put it, but in my code there is async. I'll fix the question, sorry!

Comment: Yes, I put it for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will try to explain some analyzes that I noticed. The red vertical line appears to be the moment that my page loads and not the last green horizontal bar, as I said, appears. Because the time is very fast. So apparently I am not suffering from this delay. I put a setTimeout of 10 seconds inside the useEffect and my page had already loaded while my component was not activated. After 10 seconds there was a bar that appears as usual so I don't think it's delaying my page, I think.

Maybe someone with more experience with debugger can explain it better, hugs to everyone!